# Logstash Pipe Plugin Not Working on Windows

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to execute the Logstash-output-pipe plugin, but I can't get it to work with even simplest configuration. I'm executing this command:

`bin\logstash.bat --path.settings /I:/logstash-5.2.2/config -l logs -f pipetest.conf`

... and getting this output on the console:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-06-19T11:44:07,765][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-06-19T11:44:07,797][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-06-19T11:44:07,968][INFO ][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Opening pipe {:command=>"echo hello"}
[2017-06-19T11:44:07,984][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-06-19T16:44:07.828Z,
          "host" => "v10072384",
      "@version" => "1",
         "clock" => 1,
          "type" => "heartbeat"
}
[2017-06-19T11:44:17,819][ERROR][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Error writing to pipe, closing pipe. {:command=>"echo hello", :pipe=>#<PipeWrapper:0x5a0d967d @pipe=#<IO:fd 448>, @active=true>}
[2017-06-19T11:44:17,819][INFO ][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Closing pipe "echo hello"
[2017-06-19T11:44:17,834][INFO ][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Opening pipe {:command=>"echo hello"}
[2017-06-19T11:44:17,912][INFO ][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Starting stale pipes cleanup cycle {:pipes=>{"echo hello"=>#<PipeWrapper:0x19499944 @pipe=#<IO:fd 450>, @active=true>}}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-06-19T16:44:17.803Z,
          "host" => "v10072384",
      "@version" => "1",
         "clock" => 2,
          "type" => "heartbeat"
}
[2017-06-19T11:44:27,819][ERROR][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Error writing to pipe, closing pipe. {:command=>"echo hello", :pipe=>#<PipeWrapper:0x19499944 @pipe=#<IO:fd 450>, @active=false>}
[2017-06-19T11:44:27,819][INFO ][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Closing pipe "echo hello"
[2017-06-19T11:44:27,819][INFO ][logstash.outputs.pipe    ] Opening pipe {:command=>"echo hello"}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-06-19T16:44:27.803Z,
          "host" => "v10072384",
      "@version" => "1",
         "clock" => 3,
          "type" => "heartbeat"
}
```

Here is my Logstash config file:

```
input {
    heartbeat {
        message => "sequence"
        interval => 10
        type => "heartbeat"
    }
}
output {
    pipe {
        command => "echo hello"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

I'm running Logstash version 5.2.2, Logstash-output-pipe plugin version 3.0.2 on Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit), Service Pack 1.

Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on the pipe plugin and switched to the exec plugin.